# how to count selected number of images for multiple input files

Tags: php

`count($_FILES['productimg']['name'])` is working if input is multiple, like `<input type="file" name="productimg[]" multiple>`.

However, if I use inputs multiple times, it is not working, like:

```
<input type="file" name="productimg[]" class="fileinpt">
<input type="file" name="productimg[]" class="fileinpt">
<input type="file" name="productimg[]" class="fileinpt">
...
```

Comment: print ``$_FILES['productimg']`` and try to debug it yourself.

Comment: try this one /*for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) { echi $i; }*/

Answer (score 0):

Use array_filter: http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter.php

```
count(array_filter($_FILES['productimg']['name']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_filter`

```
   echo count(array_filter($_FILES['productimg']['name']));
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP ($_FILES) will take the value of the last line, since all 3 input has the same name in the value attribute. That's why you are not getting the count you expected.

You have to manually specify the index, as shown below:

```
<input type="file" name="productimg[0]" class="fileinpt">
<input type="file" name="productimg[1]" class="fileinpt">
<input type="file" name="productimg[2]" class="fileinpt">
```

I have noticed that, this only happens in PHP, it works in other languages such as Java and Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

```
/** index.php **/
<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Send these files:<br />
<input type="file" name="userfile[]"  multiple>
  <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
</form>

/* file-upload.php */ 
<?php
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($_FILES['userfile']['name']); $i++) {
        echo $i;
    }
     ?>
```

Comment: where did you get `$_FILES['userfile']['name']` from? Did you copy this from your project?